# Table is mutating in an after insert trigger

Tags: sql, database, triggers

I'm having a problem when I insert data into my tables because of some of my triggers. For example, the following
trigger makes sure that a professor is not a student.

```
CREATE TRIGGER StudentOrProfessor2
AFTER INSERT ON Professor
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   DELETE FROM Professor
   WHERE (:NEW.ID IN (SELECT Student.ID FROM Student));
END;
/
```

However, when I insert a tuple into the Professor relation, I get the following error.

```
SQL> INSERT INTO Professor VALUES('44415676', '246813579', 'Mathematics', '2', '000070000', '317', '3921234');
INSERT INTO Professor VALUES('44415676', '246813579', 'Mathematics', '2', '000070000', '317', '3921234')
           *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-04091: table S11022CZ.PROFESSOR is mutating, trigger/function may not see
it
ORA-06512: at "S11022CZ.STUDENTORPROFESSOR2", line 2
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'S11022CZ.STUDENTORPROFESSOR2'
```

I'm not quite sure what to do in order to get around this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain you can't create a trigger on a table and then modify that table within the trigger. Are you trying to ensure that a student is not inserted into the professor table? is ID an internal database key (1,2,3,4....) or is it a business key which has some meaning? (i.e. S11022CZ)

If it's a meaningless internal database key (such as an incrementing number) then what if you have Student Joe Bloggs, ID 73. Then you create a Professor record Prof Juluis Sumner, and he has an ID of 73?

Basically I think there is a database design issue here.